# Tableau to MongoDB Connector

Tags: mongodb, tableau-api, business-intelligence

We are integrating Tableau with MongoDB and wants to decide on cost effective way connecting with MongoDB. We used trial version of Simba and that seem to be costing around $3000/year. Are there other options which are cheaper? We are not on enterprise version of MongoDB so BI Connector is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Drill](https://drill.apache.org/) has a Mongo Storage Plugin which allows Drill to be used as an 'interrogator' for MongoDB. Drill's ODBC driver can provide BI tools (such as Tableau) with access to MongoDB via Drill.

The setup would be something like:

1. Install Drill
2. Add the MongoDB Storage Plugin to your Drill installation
3. Verify access via the Drill server and using Drill's ODBC driver to MongoDB
4. Configure Tableau to use Drill's ODBC driver

More details in the docs:

- [Drill's MongoDB Plugin](https://drill.apache.org/docs/mongodb-storage-plugin/)
- [Using Drill with BI Tools](https://drill.apache.org/docs/using-drill-with-bi-tools/)
- [Tableau Examples](https://drill.apache.org/docs/tableau-examples/)

This solution is free (or has no licensing costs, at any rate) but it is somewhat bespoke and cobbled together. My own experience is that ...

- Installing Drill is a no brainer
- Installing the MongoDB Storage Plugin is a no brainer
- Drill's MongoDB Storage Plugin isn't very widely used (or at least it isn't under active development) so you'll likely find the driver works fine but you might find issues with the MongoDB query capabilities providing by Drill's plugin. For example `LIKE` and `IN` operators are not supported.

Comment: Thank you! We are only interested in connecting tableau with MongoDB and building reports. In this case, do we have to use Drill's MongoDB Storage Plugin? That will alleviate the issue of not being able to use LIKE and IN operators.

Comment: @user3616677 Yes, you'd need the MongoDB Storage Pluging. Perhaps the use of the word "storage" makes you think it is for _writing data into_ MongoDB but it is not, instead it is for _reading data from_ MongoDB. Drill provides a service layer on top of numerous storage solutions, the term "storage plugin" applies to the piece which integrates Drill with a particular storage solution. This plugin - for MongoDB - at least is read only, not read/write. WIthout it you could connect to Drill (using its driver) but Drill would be unable to serve up any data from MongoDB.